Stackable and unstackable numbers
Consider boxes stacked on top of each other.
Boxes on the bottom row are labeled 1.
Boxes not on the bottom row must be supported directly below, and are labeled as the sum of the 2 or 3 boxes they are directly above, including diagonally.
Examples: The first 9 numbers can be generated like this:
(Ignore the dots that are only meant to help you identify the horizontal position of the numbers.)



1
2.
.3.
4.
5..
.6..
.7.
.8..
..9..




.
11
111
22
23.
.33.
232
233.
.333.


.
..
...
11
111
1111
111
1111
11111



The challenge: List the numbers that cannot be generated this way. We call these numbers 'unstackable'.
Input: A positive integer n.
Output: [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n], the list of the first n unstackable numbers. This list might be an array or given term at term, at your option.
Test cases:



n
1
2
12
19
30




a(n)
11
31
139
199
263



Credits: Erich Friedman proposed this sequence to the OEIS, still under consideration.
This is code-golf, so each language's shortest code in bytes wins.

JavaScript (V8), 150 bytes
Prints the sequence forever (slowly).
for(n=9;a=[];o<n&&print(n))for(++n;a.push(1)<n;g(a))g=(a,p)=>a[i=1]<n&&g([p,...a]=a.map(v=>(v+=~-p-~a[p=v,i++])-n?v:o=n))&a.pop(g(a))&g(a)&g([p,...a])

Try it online!
Commented
for(                // outer loop:
  n = 9;            //   start with n = 9 (*)
  a = [];           //   start each iteration with a = []
  o < n && print(n) //   if o < n, n is unstackable -> print it
)                   //
  for(              //   inner loop:
    ++n;            //     increment n
    a.push(1) < n;  //     push 1 in a[], stop if a[] has n elements
    g(a)            //     invoke g with a[]
  )                 //
    g = (           //     g is a recursive function taking:
      a,            //       a[] = current row
      p             //       p = variable required in the scope of g,
    ) =>            //           initially undefined
    a[i = 1] < n && //     stop if a[1] >= n or a[1] is undefined
    g(              //     otherwise, do a 1st recursive call:
      [p, ...a] =   //       save the result of map() in p and a[]
      a.map(v =>    //       for each value v in a[]:
        ( v +=      //         compute the sum of the boxes
          ~-p - ~a[ //         below the current box: v + p + a[i]
            p = v,  //         update p to v
            i++     //         increment i
          ]         //
        ) - n ?     //         if the result is not n:
          v         //           just yield v
        :           //         else:
          o = n     //           n is stackable -> update o to n
      )             //       end of map()
    )               //     end of recursive call()
    & a.pop(g(a))   //     2nd call without the 1st term
    & g(a)          //     3rd call without the 1st and last terms
    & g([p, ...a])  //     4th call without the last term

(*) We can safely ignore \$n=1\$ to \$n=9\$ which are all stackable. Besides, our code would not work for \$n\in[1\dots3]\$. But we do need to process a stackable number (\$n=10\$) before processing the first unstackable one (\$n=11\$) to make sure that the variable \$o\$ is defined before it's tested.

Charcoal, 85 bytes
ＮθＷ‹Ｌυθ«→≔…¹Ｘ³ⅈυ≔Ｅ⊕⊗ⅈＥ⊕κ¹ηＦη«≔⁻υκυ≔ＥκΣ✂κ∧μ⊖μ⁺²μ¹κＦＥ²✂κλＦＥ²✂⮌λμ¿∧μ∧‹⌊μＸ³ⅈ¬№ημ⊞ημ»»Ｉ…υθ

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:
Ｎθ

Input n.
Ｗ‹Ｌυθ«

Repeat until at least n unstackable numbers have been found.
→

Start considering wider and taller stacks.
≔…¹Ｘ³ⅈυ

Consider unstackable numbers up to a value of 3ˣ.
≔Ｅ⊕⊗ⅈＥ⊕κ¹η

Consider stacks with bases of widths 1 to 2x+1.
Ｆη«

Loop over each stack.
≔⁻υκυ

Remove any stackable numbers.
≔ＥκΣ✂κ∧μ⊖μ⁺²μ¹κ

Calculate the next layer.
ＦＥ²✂κλＦＥ²✂⮌λμ

Consider the layer with the first and/or last element(s) removed.
¿∧μ∧‹⌊μＸ³ⅈ¬№ημ⊞ημ

If this is a new stack and not too tall then add this stack for further consideration.
»»Ｉ…υθ

Output the first n unstackable numbers.

05AB1E, 36 bytes
∞ʒÐUÅ1"DXª1èX‹iŒε0.øü3OD®.V)"©.V˜Xå≠

Outputs the infinite sequence. Unfortunately, it's extremely slow, so barely even outputs \$a(1)=11\$ within 60 seconds on TIO..
(Don't) try it online.
Explanation:
∞                 # Push the infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
 ʒ                # Filter it by:
  DU              #  Store a copy of the current value in variable `X`
   Å1             #  Push a list of that many 1s
     "..."        #  Push the recursive string explained below
          ©       #  Store this string in variable `®`
           .V     #  Pop and evaluate it as 05AB1E code
             ˜    #  Flatten it
              Xå  #  Check whether `X` is in this flattened list
                ≠ #  Invert the check, since we only want unstackable numbers
                  # (after which the filtered infinite list is lazily output
                  # implicitly)

D                 # Create a copy of the current list
 Xª               # Append `X` in case the list is of length 1
   1è             # Pop and get the second item (0-based 1st)
     X‹i          # If it's still smaller than `X`, continue:
 Œ                #  Get all substrings of this list
  ε               #  Map over each substring:
   0.ø            #   Surround it with a leading and trailing 0
      ü3          #   Pop and get all overlapping triplets
        O         #   Sum each overlapping triplet
         D        #   Duplicate this list of sums
          ®.V     #   Do a recursive call on the copy
             )    #   Wrap everything currently on the stack into a list


Python3, 498 bytes
lambda:sorted({*range(1,max(k:={j for k in range(1,20)for j in F(k,700)})+1)}-k)
def F(b,C):
 q,S=[([1]*b,[])],[]
 for b,t in q:
  if any(k>C for k in b):continue
  if len(b)==1:yield b[0];continue
  Q=[(0,[0]*len(b),b)]*(b!=[])
  for I,r,B in Q:
   if I==len(r):q+=[T:=([k for k in r if k],t+[b])]*(T not in S);S+=[T];continue
   if I==0 or I==len(r)-1:Q+=[(I+1,r,B)]
   for m in[[I-1,I,I+1],[I,I+1],[I-1,I]]:
    if all(len(r)>i>=0 for i in m):R=[*r];R[I]=sum(B[u]for u in m);Q+=[(I+1,R,B)];break

Try it online!

Perl 5, 232 bytes
@S=0..($m=20*($N=pop));sub f{@S[@_]=();!$s{"@$_"}++&&(grep$_&&$m>$_,@$_)&&f(@$_)for[0,@_[2..$#_]],[@_[0..@_-3],0],[0,@_[2..@_-3],0],[0,(map$_[$_+1]?$_[$_]+$_[$_+1]+$_[$_+2]:0,0..@_-3),0]}f(0,(1)x(8+$N/20),0);$_&&$N&&$N--&&say for@S;

Try it online!
